# What is meaning of "end-to-end" or "link-to-link" flow control?

Tags: computer-science

I am reading the paper "Ethernet Goes Real-time: a Survey on Research and Technological Developments".

In this paper, it says "Flow control can be implemented on a link-by-link or end-to-end basis"

Link-to-link means flow control examines only an individual link between switches or stations.

End-to-end means flow control that the switches at each end of the link communicate to throttle back the end stations that are originating the traffic.

If device A trying to transmit data to device D and device A ~ D are chain connected like below which means device D only can receive data from device A via device B and device C,

device A -> device B -> device C -> device D

I think the link-to-link implementation works in the following way: If device D's buffer is full, it sends a signal to device C to stop transmitting data. Device C then stops transmitting data to device D but continues to receive data from device B until its buffer is full. If device C becomes full, it sends a signal to device B to stop sending data. Device B then behaves in the same manner with respect to device A. So, device A (originator of traffic) stops transmit data to device D.

On the other hand, end-to-end implementation work in the following way: If device D's buffer becomes full, a stop signal is sent to device A through device C and device B, even if their buffers are not completely full.

Am I understanding link-to-link & end-to-end flow control right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic understanding about link-by-link vs end-to-end is correct.

However the signaling based on how full the buffers are, is one way it could be implemented, however it is not the only way.

An alternate mechanism is to Acknowledge receipt of a given packet.
For example the first system could send 4 packets then wait until the first packet had been received and acknowledged before sending packet #5.

Given this strategy, each link could have an acknowledgment system or you could do an end-to-end acknowledgement where only the final receiving system sends the acknowledgments.

The acknowledgement system is based on the idea that when the network gets busy, some packets get lost (it might be the original or the acknowledgment packet) when the sender doesn't receive an acknowledgment within a certain time it resends the original packet.